# Javascript: Palindrome function undefined?

Tags: javascript, function, return, palindrome

I have been working on a palindrome function (will check if word is spelled the same forward and backwards):

```
var palinDromes = function(palMap) {
        palMap.split(" ").map(function(word) {
            var palCheck = (word.toLowerCase() === word.toLowerCase().split("").reverse().join(""));
                return palCheck;
                });
    };

console.log(palinDromes('Hannah speaks English and Malayalam'));
```

But the output is always undefined. I believe the issue is in the first step, something involving the `console.log(palinDrome(...));` transition to `palMap`, but I'm not sure what exactly.

The issue might also be that I am not returning `palCheck` correctly at the end of the function?

Comment: Without a `return` statement, the value is `undefined`.  You've got a `return` inside the `.map()` callback, but that won't help the outer function.

Comment: read on javascript closures.

Answer (score 2):

```
var palinDromes = function(palMap) {
       return  palMap.split(" ").map(function(word) {
            var palCheck = (word.toLowerCase() === word.toLowerCase().split("").reverse().join(""));
                return palCheck;
                });
    };
console.log(palinDromes('Hannah speaks English and Malayalam'));
```

EDIT: I added a return before palMap.split(" ").map(function(word) { ...